# Calling variable from another activity

Tags: android

I'm new to android. I have 2 questions.

I have a `main activity`, that has a `textbox (edit text)` called `gametext` and I have a button called `gamebutton`. Currently, the button opens a new activity called `detailsactivity` using an intent.

Now my question is, when I press the button, I want to store the input on the edit text as a string and use it for something else on details activity. how do I do this?

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),DetailsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return rootView;

}
```

Comment: USE intent.putExtra("EXTRA_UR_TEXT", UR_TEXT);

Comment: Bro please do some research work before asking...There are 1000 solutions for ur question.

Answer (score 1):

Use putExtra with intent :

```
Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),DetailsActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("yourString",editext.getText().toString());
startActivity(intent);
```

To get data into another activity then just get using intent :

```
String data = getIntent().getStringExtra("yourString");
```

Answer (score 0):

In Button click. put Edittext Input String like this.

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailsActivity.class);
i.putExtra("data_to_pass", ((EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edittext_id)).getText().toString().trim());
startActivity(i);
```

In your DetailsActivity get String using getIntent()

```
String data = getIntent().getStringExtra("data_to_pass");
```

Answer (score 0):

Add putExtra line in your onClick function

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),DetailsActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("inputValue",editText.getText().toString())
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And add the following to to get passed string in another activity

```
String inputValue = getIntent().getStringExtra("inputValue","");
```